# ggtree::facet_plot - Second panel uses xlim parameter from first one

Tags: r, ggplot2, ape-phylo, ggtree

I have performed statistical tests on lots of genera that are hierarchically structured with a tree, so I have a p-value for each of the genus in the tree.

I want to visualize both the tree and the p-value in a panel plot, as it's possible to do with [ggtree](https://bioconductor.org/packages/devel/bioc/vignettes/ggtree/inst/doc/treeAnnotation.html#plot-tree-with-associated-data).

Packages and tree data:

```
library(ape)
# source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); biocLite("ggtree")
library(ggtree)

tree <- structure(list(
  edge = structure(c(102L, 103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 
                     107L, 103L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 111L, 109L, 112L, 113L, 109L, 
                     114L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 115L, 114L, 116L, 109L, 117L, 
                     118L, 108L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 119L, 122L, 123L, 123L, 108L, 124L, 
                     125L, 126L, 125L, 127L, 127L, 108L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 130L, 129L, 
                     131L, 103L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 134L, 136L, 136L, 134L, 137L, 
                     137L, 134L, 138L, 138L, 134L, 139L, 139L, 134L, 140L, 134L, 141L, 
                     141L, 103L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 103L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 
                     146L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 103L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 153L, 157L, 
                     158L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 159L, 157L, 160L, 161L, 160L, 162L, 
                     103L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 165L, 167L, 167L, 165L, 168L, 168L, 
                     165L, 169L, 164L, 170L, 171L, 170L, 172L, 163L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 
                     175L, 175L, 173L, 176L, 177L, 177L, 177L, 173L, 178L, 179L, 179L, 
                     163L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 181L, 183L, 183L, 183L, 181L, 184L, 184L, 
                     184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 184L, 181L, 185L, 185L, 
                     185L, 181L, 186L, 181L, 187L, 187L, 181L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 188L, 
                     188L, 163L, 189L, 190L, 191L, 191L, 163L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 194L, 
                     194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 194L, 103L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 196L, 
                     199L, 200L, 103L, 201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 204L, 102L, 205L, 206L, 
                     207L, 208L, 209L, 206L, 210L, 211L, 212L, 206L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 
                     103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 1L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 2L, 
                     3L, 112L, 113L, 4L, 114L, 115L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 116L, 
                     11L, 117L, 118L, 12L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 13L, 122L, 123L, 14L, 
                     15L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 16L, 127L, 17L, 18L, 128L, 129L, 130L, 
                     19L, 20L, 131L, 21L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 22L, 136L, 23L, 
                     24L, 137L, 25L, 26L, 138L, 27L, 28L, 139L, 29L, 30L, 140L, 31L, 
                     141L, 32L, 33L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 34L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 
                     149L, 35L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 36L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 37L, 
                     157L, 158L, 159L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 160L, 161L, 43L, 162L, 
                     44L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 45L, 167L, 46L, 47L, 168L, 48L, 
                     49L, 169L, 50L, 170L, 171L, 51L, 172L, 52L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 
                     53L, 54L, 55L, 176L, 177L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 178L, 179L, 59L, 60L, 
                     180L, 181L, 182L, 61L, 183L, 62L, 63L, 64L, 184L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 
                     68L, 69L, 70L, 71L, 72L, 73L, 74L, 185L, 75L, 76L, 77L, 186L, 
                     78L, 187L, 79L, 80L, 188L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 84L, 85L, 189L, 190L, 
                     191L, 86L, 87L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 
                     94L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 95L, 199L, 200L, 96L, 201L, 202L, 
                     203L, 204L, 97L, 98L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 99L, 210L, 
                     211L, 212L, 100L, 213L, 214L, 215L, 101L), .Dim = c(214L, 2L)), 
  edge.length = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
                  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
  Nnode = 114L, 
  tip.label = c("Brachyspira", 
                "Haemophilus", "Aggregatibacter", "Acinetobacter", "Klebsiella", 
                "Salmonella", "Escherichia", "Enterobacter", "Shigella", 
                "Citrobacter", "Hafnia", "Succinatimonas", "Corallococcus", 
                "Bilophila", "Desulfovibrio", "Azospirillum", "Acidiphilium", 
                "Acetobacter", "Sutterella", "Parasutterella", "Oxalobacter", 
                "Porphyromonas", "Paraprevotella", "Prevotella", "Alistipes", 
                "Rikenella", "Tannerella", "Parabacteroides", "Odoribacter", 
                "Butyricimonas", "Bacteroides", "Coprobacter", "Barnesiella", 
                "Fusobacterium", "Coraliomargarita", "Akkermansia", "Bifidobacterium", 
                "Gordonibacter", "Eggerthella", "Cryptobacterium", "Adlercreutzia", 
                "Enterorhabdus", "Collinsella", "Olsenella", "Lactobacillus", 
                "Weissella", "Oenococcus", "Lactococcus", "Streptococcus", 
                "Enterococcus", "Staphylococcus", "Bacillus", "Dialister", 
                "Veillonella", "Megasphaera", "Megamonas", "Mitsuokella", 
                "Selenomonas", "Phascolarctobacterium", "Acidaminococcus", 
                "Oscillibacter", "Intestinibacter", "Peptoclostridium", "Peptostreptococcus", 
                "Dorea", "Roseburia", "Anaerostipes", "Tyzzerella", "Coprococcus", 
                "Blautia", "Butyrivibrio", "Marvinbryantia", "Lachnoclostridium", 
                "Oribacterium", "Flavonifractor", "Intestinimonas", "Pseudoflavonifractor", 
                "Eubacterium", "Clostridium", "Butyricicoccus", "Faecalibacterium", 
                "Ruminococcus", "Anaerotruncus", "Subdoligranulum", "Ruminiclostridium", 
                "Parvimonas", "Peptoniphilus", "Catenibacterium", "Solobacterium", 
                "Coprobacillus", "Holdemania", "Erysipelatoclostridium", 
                "Turicibacter", "Stoquefichus", "Mycoplasma", "Acholeplasma", 
                "Pyramidobacter", "Synergistes", "Methanobrevibacter", "Methanomethylophilus", 
                "Methanoculleus"), root.edge = 1), 
  .Names = c("edge", "edge.length", 
             "Nnode", "tip.label", "root.edge"), class = "phylo", order = "cladewise"
)
```

Code:

```
df <- data.frame(id = tree$tip.label, p = runif(length(tree$tip.label)))

p1 <- ggtree(tree) +
  geom_tiplab()

facet_plot(p1, panel = "p-value", data = df, geom = geom_point, aes(x = p))
```

[image]

But here, the name of the genera is truncated so I modified the `xlim` parameter to see them completly.

```
p2 <- 
  ggtree(tree) + 
  geom_tiplab() + 
  xlim(c(0,7))

facet_plot(p2, panel = "p-value", data = df, geom = geom_point, aes(x = p))
```

[image]

It works! However, `xlim` spreads to the second panel... How can I fix that?

I tried to add `xlim(0:1)` or `xlim = 0:1` in `facet_plot()` but that doesn't work...

---

**Edit** after F. Privé answer:

I need to keep my labels at the right of the branches because I have to add some labels/statistics on them. And I want them left-aligned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ggtree` provides the `xlim_expand` function specifically for that purpose.

You need to specify the limits and the panel to which you want to apply it. In you case, you want to apply it to the `Tree` panel:

```
p1 <- ggtree(tree) +
  geom_tiplab(size = 2) + 
  xlim_expand(c(0,15), panel = "Tree")

facet_plot(p1, panel = "p-value", data = df, geom = geom_point, aes(x = p))
```

[image: example_plot]

I exagerated the limits for the example but you can adjust it to your preference.

Answer (score 1):

You can play with the `hjust` and `offset` parameters (although I don't quite understand them):

```
p2 <- 
  ggtree(tree) + 
  geom_tiplab(hjust = 1, offset = 8)

facet_plot(p2, panel = "p-value", data = df, geom = geom_point, aes(x = p))
```

Comment: With `geom_tiplab(hjust = 1, offset = 0)`, it's nicer but that not exactly what I want because names are on the wrong side of the leaf... 
`offset` (default 0) controls the x-coordinates of the label with respect to the leafs.
`hjust` (default 0) is between 0 and 1 and controls where to print the labels with respect to its x-coordinates (1 is at the left and right-centerd, 0.5 is centered and 0 is at the right and left-centered)